# Randomly set image background using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

I have CSS that displays a full image covering the entire page.

```css
#backgroundjake {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff  fixed;
  background-position: top right;
  /*background-position: contain;*/
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("images/bb7.jpg");
}
```

I have been trying to understand jQuery for a while, I have these a script that simply doesnt produce results.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" >

 var images = new Array('images/bb1.jpg', 'images/bb2.jpg', 'images/bb3.jpg',    'images/bb4.jpg', 'images/bb5.jpg', 'images/bb6.jpg', 'images/bb7.jpg',     'images/bb8.jpg' );
  var num = Math.ceil( Math.random() * totalCount );
 $("#backgroundjake")).css('backgroundImage', 'url(' +images[num]+ ')');

</script>
```

I call the css class like this in the html:

```
 <div id= "backgroundjake"  name= "backgroundjake" >
```

Comment: This won't fix the overall issues I don't think, but you have an extra `)` in `$("#backgroundjake")).css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JSFiddle with a solution for your problem :

**EDIT** : I used `floor()` function instead of `ceil()` because I have noticed a bug of the random.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hajph0hr/10/)

JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var images = new Array('http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/627/300/4', 'http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/6','http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/255/200/5');
  var num = Math.floor( Math.random() * images.length );
  $("#backgroundjake").css('backgroundImage', 'url(' +images[num]+ ')');

  $("h2").click(function(){
      $(this).css('textShadow','#6374AB 4px 4px 4px');
  });
});
```

About your code, be careful when you call vars and test them. For example, you call "totalCount" var even if it's not defined in the code, so it won't works.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JavaScript `random()` Method  in order to return a random number.

More infos here :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var array_images = new Array('http://placehold.it/350x150/000000', 'http://placehold.it/350x150/e63c3c', 'http://placehold.it/350x150/3ce690');

  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * array_images.length);

  $("#backgroundjake").css('background-image', 'url(' + array_images[num] + ')');


});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#backgroundjake {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff fixed;
  background-position: top right;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/350x150/e63c3c");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="backgroundjake">
  <h2>
    lorem ipsum
  </h2>
</div>
```